# Upstart unknown job problem

Tags: upstart, nginx

I set up nginx according [to instructions here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/lnGvHyRzX7w/N8eDnwJPXuAJ) and it all went well but I am unable to start with

```
$ start <my app name>
```

I created `/etc/init/nomilkfor.me.conf` (this is the domain name) and this is what is in the file:

```
description "ubuntu 13.10 on Samsung laptop"
author "zeynel"
                                                   
start on startup
stop on shutdown
                                                   
setuid deploy
chdir /deploy
console log
                                                   
env PORT=4000
exec java -jar my-webapp-0.1.0-standalone.jar
```

I reload nginx with

```
$ sudo nginx -s reload
```

and I try

```
$ start nomilkfor.me
```

but I get

```
start: Unknown job: nomilkfor.me
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried to open the log files in `/var/log/upstart` but I could not open them with nano.

Answer (score 7):

I found that if there is any errors in the script file the start command will report "Unknown job".

You can check the script using `init-checkconf /etc/init/nomilkfor.me` (not as root but as a user account)

Once all errors was fixed there the `start nomilkfor.me` might work.